# Check for timeout in wait() loop

Tags: java, locking, timeout

I want to check for a condition in a guarded `wait()` loop with a user-specified *total* timeout, similar to how `LinkedBlockingQueue.poll()` works.

For example `collection` can be appended to by different threads, but only when the collection contains a value equating to `myItem` *within* `timeout`, should the loop terminate successfully. If the user-specified timeout elapses, it should throw.

This is my current best approach:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
synchronized (collection) {
    while (!collection.contains(myItem)) {
        long remaining = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime - timeout;
        if (remaining < 0)
            throw new TimeoutException();

        collection.wait(remaining);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that `System.currentTimeMillis()` (or `System.nanoTime()`) is called inside a synchronized context. IntelliJ's warning states:

> While not necessarily representing a problem, such calls cause an expensive context switch, and are best kept out of synchronized contexts, if possible.

I wonder how much impact this 'expensive context switch' will have in practice, with Oracle JVM 8?

---

This is one alternative I came up with, but I don't like this as the actual timeout becomes `⌊timeout/10⌋*10 + delta`. and the error will probably be much worse than the context switch.

```
synchronized (collection) {
    int loops = 0;
    while (!collection.contains(myItem)) {
        if(loops++ > timeout / 10)
            throw new TimeoutException();

        collection.wait(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is the system clock, and can change if someone changes the current date / time.  It's not really a good way to accurately measure elapsed time.  Use `System.nanoTime()` instead, which is invariant to system clock changes.

Comment: This question must be from before I learned that fact, and since then I've been reinforcing it, on other SO questions too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be fine with `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Even though the method itself is not `synchronized`, mostly native method call internally would be `synchronized`.

Read this old but still useful article about the same thing.

https://www.devx.com/java-zone/28685/